# c++ in visual studio 2019 game window showing blank screen Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I'm working through beginning C++ Game Programming by John Horton and it has been going well.  Recently though when running the Local Windows Debugger the game window pops up but doesn't show anything, just a blank window.

It runs, it never showed it ran into any errors while running, I scavenged over my code and can't find anything wrong with it.  I went back and ran one of the games I had made from earlier in the book and worked, and now that just shows a blank screen in the game window too!  I've tried googling and stackoverflow and even looking through the similar questions while making this but no dice.

You can see the code I'm using at the book's github repo ([Beginning C++ Game Programming github repo](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Beginning-Cpp-Game-Programming-Second-Edition)), and the issue started in chapter 9, but my hunch is it's not the code since the game that originally worked before is also only showing a blank game window now. Running on Windows 10. Alienware Aurora R7.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you have a *specific* question about the behavior of your code please provide a [Minimal,  Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People shouldn't have to go track down some off-site resource to see what code you are referring to.

Comment: Maybe the game images are in the wrong folder and the code you are running does not handle the error condition or does not print any type of error message. With that said you probably need to debug. I doubt anyone can help with this. All we can do is guess.

Comment: @coryKramer Very sorry, since I don't know where exactly in the code the problem might be, and it's a dozen folders of code, I thought sharing the repo would be the most effective method.  I'll be sure to be more specific in the future. Thank you for taking the time to provide feedback.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I have checked the file paths and made sure they are correct. I'll look into resources for learning how to debug.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Use a debugger, logger or print statements (or all of them).  The challenge is to find out where in the code the window changes, then analyze the code around it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official SFML document:

> The loadFromFile function can sometimes fail with no obvious reason.
> First, check the error message that SFML prints to the standard output
> (check the console). If the message is unable to open file, make sure
> that the working directory (which is the directory that any file path
> will be interpreted relative to) is what you think it is: When you run
> the application from your desktop environment, the working directory
> is the executable folder. However, when you launch your program from
> your IDE (Visual Studio, Code::Blocks, ...) the working directory
> might sometimes be set to the project directory instead. This can
> usually be changed quite easily in the project settings.

Therefore ensure your image is firstly named correctly and secondendly make sure it is in the correct folder i.e. in your working directory.